# How to conditionally fail Flyway migration script for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, flyway

I need to execute update SQL via Flyway. AFAIK, update statement will execute successfully even if `ITEM_ID` does not exist in the database table. I want this migration to fail if any `ITEM_ID` was not found.

What I tried:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) TABLE1 WHERE ITEM_ID IN (3, 5, 7)) != 3 
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Unexpected IDs. Aborting.', 20, -1) with log
END
GO

update TABLE1 set FIELD1='AA' where ITEM_ID=3;
update TABLE1 set FIELD1='BB' where ITEM_ID=5;
update TABLE1 set FIELD1='CC' where ITEM_ID=7;
GO
```

`raiserror` doesn't seem to work if the database user is not the administrator (my case).

Is there any way to that with SQL Server-based migrations?

### Update 1:

`raiserror` works for severity level 11.

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) TABLE1 WHERE ITEM_ID IN (3, 5, 7)) != 3 
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Unexpected IDs. Aborting.', 11, -1)
END
GO
update TABLE1 set FIELD1='AA' where ITEM_ID=3;
update TABLE1 set FIELD1='BB' where ITEM_ID=5;
update TABLE1 set FIELD1='CC' where ITEM_ID=7;
GO
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: `RAISERROR` works for everyone, but not if you use severity 20 (which requires `WITH LOG`, which in turn requires sysadmin permissions). Use severity 11, which is enough to return an error to the caller, and `SET NOEXEC ON` to force the rest of the script not to execute.

Comment: I checked. It seems to work without `SET NOEXEC ON`. What is the purpose of `SET NOEXEC ON`? Will it make the script execution successful (that will make Flyway to mark this migration as Success, which is not what I want)?

Comment: The purpose of `SET NOEXEC ON` is to ["compile each query but not execute it"](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/set-noexec-transact-sql). (`SET PARSEONLY ON` is even more conservative than that, as it does not even compile anything.) In effect, it is the "stop doing anything" flag of T-SQL. I have no idea what Flyway does; I would hope that the script raising an error is enough to mark it as unsuccessful.